# Execution order for Dynamics 365 plugin for same entity but with different messages

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Hi I need one suggestion
For email entity I have 3 plugins, all of them are pre operation and sync
3 plugins one for each create, update and send message
All of them are having execution order 1
Is it ok to have same execution order for same entity pre operations, even though the messages are different.
Will there be any concurrency issue?

[Plugins those are registered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TLYc.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the messages are different there should be no issues, if the messages are the same (like all 3 plugins on Create) is necessary to check the logic inside the plugins, if they are independent (like no common fields that are updated by a different plugin are involved) or not